# How to better understand Coffeescript/JavaScript mixins?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have been reading up on Mixins using Coffeescript or just plain Javascript from the following sources:

http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html (near the bottom)

and

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

And while I am able to compile the various examples, I have a major question that seems to be preventing me from making progress in comprehending them.

I have no idea what in the world is going on. To start, I will explain the Coffeescript that is confusing me.

```
moduleKeywords = ['extended', 'included']

    class Module
      @extend: (obj) ->
        for key, value of obj when key not in moduleKeywords
          @[key] = value

        obj.extended?.apply(@)
        this

      @include: (obj) ->
        for key, value of obj when key not in moduleKeywords
          # Assign properties to the prototype
          @::[key] = value

        obj.included?.apply(@)
        this
```

A number of questions come up here.

1. First of all, what are we accomplishing with the `moduleKeywords` variable? I'm not understanding what that is doing.
2. Secondly, how does `extended?.apply(@)` work? What is really going on here? I can look at the JavaScript compilation and see the following code ..

```
Module.extend = function(obj) {
      var key, value, _ref;
      for (key in obj) {
        value = obj[key];
        if (__indexOf.call(moduleKeywords, key) < 0) {
          this[key] = value;
        }
      }
      if ((_ref = obj.extended) != null) {
        _ref.apply(this);
      }
      return this;
    };
```

Can anyone shed some general light on this?

From deeper down in `The Little Book on Coffeescript`, I see an implementation.

```
ORM = 
  find: (id) ->
  create: (attrs) ->
  extended: ->
    @include
      save: -> 

class User extends Module
  @extend ORM
```

Here is how I read this:

- create literal `ORM`.
- Declare method `find` accepting a parameter.
- Declare method 'create' accepting a parameter.
- Declare method 'extended', with sub-method 'include', with sub-method 'save'.

#### This is where I get the most lost.

The literal `ORM` has a method, `extended`, and then `Module` is implemented/extended by the 'class' `User`. So I take this to mean that `User` has the same shape as `Module`. That part makes sense so far, simplistic inheritance. But then I get lost on `@extend ORM`.

`@extend` is a method on `Module`, but what is the `extended` method doing? When is it called? How is it implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `extend` copies the methods from the "module" object onto the object being extended
- `include` copies the methods from the "module" object onto the **prototype** of the object being extended

1 The `moduleKeywords` is used to protect some methods of the module, so the are not copied to object, because they have special meaning

2 The `extended?.apply(@)` says that **if the module has a property named `extended` than assume it's a function and then call this function having the "this" in the function equal to @, @ being the extended object**, you can think of it as saying something like (although not quite, but it's just an intuition)  `@.extended()` (@ == this in coffeescript)

["apply" function in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
[the existential operator in CS](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)

Answer (score 0):

You are confused by meaning and use for *extended* and *included* Module keywords. But it is explained in book that those are used as *callbacks* after extending and including.

So in final example ORM has "extended" callback. The "extend" function will on end call "extended" and pass it @ (or this or in our example User) so @(this.)include will also run on User and it will include function "save".

You could also do the reverse:

```
ORM = 
  save ->
  included: ->
    @extend
      find: (id) ->
      create: (attrs) ->

class User extends Module
  @include ORM
```